# What does arena means in the output of JVM NMT

Tags: java, linux, memory, jvm, malloc

I ran 'jcmd  VM.native_memory detail' for a Java application, and the output was like:

```
Total: reserved=4741MB, committed=3506MB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=2350MB, committed=2350MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=2350MB, committed=2350MB)

-                     Class (reserved=1676MB, committed=751MB)
                            (classes #151986)
                            (  instance classes #144245, array classes #7741)
                            (malloc=24MB #383379)
                            (mmap: reserved=1652MB, committed=727MB)
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=628MB, committed=626MB)
                            (    used=613MB)
                            (    free=13MB)
                            (    waste=0MB =0.00%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1024MB, committed=100MB)
                            (    used=92MB)
                            (    free=8MB)
                            (    waste=0MB =0.00%)

-                    Thread (reserved=214MB, committed=26MB)
                            (thread #219)
                            (stack: reserved=213MB, committed=25MB)
                            (malloc=1MB #1316)
...
OMIT SOME LINES HERE 
...

-                  Internal (reserved=10MB, committed=10MB)
                            (malloc=10MB #9058)
-                    Symbol (reserved=44MB, committed=44MB)
                            (malloc=41MB #560526)               --> isn't malloc function backed up by arena under glibc?
                            (arena=2MB #1)                      --> what does this line mean?

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=19MB, committed=19MB)
                            (malloc=1MB #7348)
                            (tracking overhead=18MB)

-        Shared class space (reserved=17MB, committed=17MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=17MB, committed=17MB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=6MB, committed=6MB).           --> What does this block suggest?
                            (malloc=6MB)

-                    Module (reserved=3MB, committed=3MB)
                            (malloc=3MB #18535)
```

Take **Symbol** block for example, what is the difference between malloc and arena? The java application is running on Linux using glibc, so I think (maybe I am wrong) it is arena that actually takes responsibility for memory management. But why is there another separated line below noting memory allocated by arena?

And what does **Arena Chunk** block mean?
Could you please enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to glibc arenas.

In HotSpot, Arena is a structure for fast native memory allocation, optimized for the particular pattern:

1. Allocation from Arena is thread local. No synchronization is involved.
2. Memory from an Arena cannot be reclaimed partially. Arena is disposed all at once.

A typical use case for Arena allocation is JIT compilation. When the JIT compiler works, it allocates many small objects (e.g. IR graph nodes). These objects are used locally just by one compiler thread. The life time of these temporary objects is short: when the compilation of a method completes, the entire Arena holding all these objects is deleted at once.

Arena consists of large chunks allocated with a regular `malloc`. Allocation inside an Arena is a simple pointer increment. When Arena runs out of free space, a new chunk is created.

`(arena=2MB #1)` in the above NMT report means that the Symbol area has an Arena which includes one chunk of 2MB.

`Arena Chunk` section summarizes all active Arenas.